# QMAIL Server replied: 451 qq trouble creating files in queue (#4.3.0)

Tags: email

Getting the above error when I send and email using both telnet interface and the web interface. I am using qmail. Can someone pls help.

This is what i get when I run qmailctl stat

```
>[root@pristine qmail-send]# qmailctl stat 
/service/qmail-send: up (pid 20193) 2952 seconds
/service/qmail-send/log: up (pid 20195) 2952 seconds
/service/qmail-smtpd: up (pid 20199) 2952 seconds
/service/qmail-smtpd/log: up (pid 7692) 1 seconds
/service/qmail-pop3d: up (pid 20203) 2952 seconds
/service/qmail-pop3d/log: up (pid 7693) 1 seconds
messages in queue: 0
messages in queue but not yet preprocessed: 0
```

After running ps aux on the smtp processes I got the following

```
ps aux | grep -i qmail
root      5606  0.0  0.0  1344  224 pts/1    S    13:24   0:00 readproctitle service errors: ...ure?supervise: fatal: unable to acquire qmail-pop3d/supervise/lock: temporary failure?supervise: fatal: unable to acquire log/supervise/lock: temporary failure?supervise: fatal: unable to acquire qmail-smtpd/supervise/lock:
root      5674  0.0  0.0  1344  224 pts/1    S    13:24   0:00 readproctitle service errors: ...ry failure?supervise: fatal: unable to acquire qmail-pop3d/supervise/lock: temporary failure?supervise: fatal: unable to acquire log/supervise/lock: temporary failure?supervise: fatal: unable to acquire log/supervise/lock: t
root      5679  0.0  0.0  1352  268 pts/1    S    13:25   0:00 supervise qmail-send
root      5689  0.0  0.0  1352  268 ?        S    13:25   0:00 supervise qmail-pop3d
root      5691  0.0  0.0  1352  264 ?        S    13:25   0:00 supervise qmail-smtpd
root     11432  0.0  0.0  1608  456 pts/1    S    13:36   0:00 grep -i qmail
root     11600  0.0  0.0  1372  284 ?        S    May15   0:00 tcpserver -H -R -v -c100 0 110 qmail-popup mail.pristine.gm /home/vpopmail/bin/vchkpw qmail-pop3d Maildir
vpopmail 11601  0.0  0.0  1544  456 ?        S    May15   0:00 /usr/local/bin/tcpserver -v -R -l mail.pristine.gm -x /etc/tcp.smtp.cdb -c 30 -u 510 -g 505 0 smtp /var/qmail/bin/qmail-smtpd mail.pristine.gm /home/vpopmail/bin/vchkpw /usr/bin/true
qmaill   11615  0.0  0.0  1496  328 ?        S    May15   2:01 multilog t s100000 n20 /var/log/qmail/qmail-pop3d
```

Comment: Did you check queue disk free space and access rights?

Comment: I deleted all messages in the queue and also ran qfixq script to fix the permision problem but I am still having the same problem.

Comment: I would check the [log files](http://qmail.jms1.net/logfiles.shtml) and possibly allow verbose/debugging output. --- Also the disk space can be occupied by something else than the queues. I suggest checking it with `df`.

Comment: When I did a df command it shows only 56% of the disk been used.

    [mjarju@pristine ]$ df
    Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
    /dev/vzfs             62914560  33751044  29163516  54% /
    [mjarju@pristine ]$

I used multilog with the following command below but when i checked the current log file it was empty

    multilog t '-* * > *' '-* * < *' /var/log/qmail/qmail-smtpd \ '-*' '+* * > 5*' /var/log/qmail/smtpd-er

Comment: When I send a message to the mail server this is the error i get.
The message identifier is:     1VdfpX-00027i-Q5
The date of the message is:    Tue, 5 Nov 2013 12:33:38 +0000
The subject of the message is: test

 Delay reason: SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
 host 216.154.222.93 [216.154.222.93]: 451 qq trouble creating files in queue (#4.3.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue. The error is due to permissioning in the ../qmail/queue folder. Normally only the user qmailq would be able to create queues in mess folder. But in this case vpopmail would be trying to create a queue.

Comment: Fix the queue using queue-repair script.

Comment: asembereng, Does this fix your problem? Do your subsequent messages get written with by the correct uid and permissions in the queue?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this on a qmail installation on OpenBSD and realised that it was because the `qmail-queue` binary is marked SetUID (which it needs),

```
# ls -l /var/qmail/bin/qmail-queue
-rws--x--x  1 qmailq  qmail 21240 Mar 31 12:52 qmail-queue
#
```

meanwhile the disk partition holding `qmail-queue` had the `nosuid` flag set,

```
# cat /etc/fstab
...
disk_id_string.e /var ffs rw,nodev,nosuid 1 2
```

so `qmail-queue` couldn't become user `qmailq` to place items in the queue. Solved by removing that `nosuid` and rebooting (or just remount `/var`).